# How disable default drag of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm french so I'm sorry for my english.
I try to do a simple drag and drop like in : https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/ but if we replace 1, 2 and 3 by a `<img>`, the drag and drop doesn't work because of the default dragndrop of the `<img>` open the file in firefox and in edge that let the image with 0.4 opacity

I try to disable this behaviour with `getElementsByTagName('img').ondragstart = function(){return false;};`
but that doesn't change anything
I try also to put `onmousedown='return false'` in my img but It block the real drag and drop too

Edit: I found on the web I put in my Css :

```css
 img{
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

And all work in Edge not in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this the answers are in the document you're referring to already. You need to prevent the default browser behavior using event.preventDefault(). You can put this inside a handler function e.g. function handleDrop(e) {e.preventDefault()} and then call it on drop event like - myimage.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);

Comment: I think to that before but it's weird : it stop the personalized drag and drop to do this job

Comment: Thanks you I find thanks to you, I put e.preventDefault() for all the objet when I drag an object